# angular2-rc1 http.post not working correctly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, typescript, angular2-http

I am creating one angular2 app in which I am using http in my service to make `POST` call to `mongoDB`.

When I am making a `POST` call for the first time it is working fine i.e. entry is inserted into database correctly but when I am sending the data for second time it is not getting inserted.

If I am reloading the page after first insertion then its working fine.

I did some debugging and found that during second request my `req.body` is blank.

Here is my code:

**page.service.ts**

```
savePage(page: Object) {
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let url = this.baseUrl+'/pm/pages/';      
    let data={};
    data["data"]=page;
    console.log(data); //this is printing both times correctly
    //on second request data is blank where as it works correctly for first time       
    return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(data),{headers: this.headers})
        .map((res: Response) => res.json()).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Here is my data in req.body shown in node services.

**First Request**:

```
body:{ 
    data:{ 
        name: 'wtwetwet',
        desc: 'wetwetwetetwte',
        isPublic: true,
        createdBy: 'Bhushan'
    }
}
```

**Second Request**

```
body: {}
```

any inputs?

Comment: Google Chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit)..is it a browser issue?

Comment: I guess not. No idea what can cause this problem.

Comment: there are no issue with my node service because I tested it using Advanced Rest Client..and it is working fine for multiple requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally realised that my method used to set content-type each time it was getting called.

Thus changing code from :

```
savePage(page: Object) {
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let url = this.baseUrl+'/pm/pages/';      
    let data={};
    data["data"]=page;           
    return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(data),{headers: this.headers})
    .map((res: Response) => res.json()).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

to:

```
savePage(page: Object) {
    this.headers=new Headers();
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let url = this.baseUrl+'/pm/pages/';      
    let data={};
    data["data"]=page;             
    return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(data),{headers: this.headers})
    .map((res: Response) => res.json()).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

did the trick for me.
Actually we need to set headers only once while making a rest call,but in my code it was already set thus creating new Headers Object helped me clearing any previously set configurations.

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: I am getting same error but already header is set only once. I am using rc4. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

It looks more like a backend thing. You should however include the code that subscribes on this http call.

By the way, why are you using RC1? Angular 2 is now on RC5.